# Xamarin Change RowHeight for each row in Grid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to change the RowHeight for each row in the Grid, so I gave every row a name like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row0_Height"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="Row1_Height"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="Row2_Height"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="30" x:Name="Row3_Height"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

But how can I set those values using c# code?

Comment: Why are you not using RowHeight as Auto? So it automatically adjusts as per the needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can do this at xaml. Or At least I don't know. The easier way will be do this at code behind and creating a grid or setting grid up with new row definition.

Something like this will work:

```
MyGrid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();

for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++) 
{

  MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1,  GridUnitType.Star) });  
   MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new G    GridLength(1,    GridUnitType.Star) });

}
```

Or you can try to bind the height :

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RowSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And Model:

```
private float _rowSize = 230;

    public float RowSize
    { 
            get {
            return _rowSize ;    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, but do I need to remove the RowDefinitions in the axml then?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk yes , You don't need them any more.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk may be second way will be better for you.

Comment: And do I need to put that Model part in the page constructor?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk you RowSize, no just you have to define a property and set its value. It could be something fixed or you can calculate it. First solution you have to call at constructor or something equalent.

Answer (score 0):

the C# equivalent of this code would be :-

```
Row0_Height.Height = new GridLength(40);
Row1_Height.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
Row2_Height.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
Row3_Height.Height = new GridLength(30);
```

Comment: Row0_Height is not declared in this scope?

Comment: Can is the Grid inside the Page or inside a ListView ?

Comment: Inside a ListView

Comment: That is the reason why you are unable to set it into C#. If you want to do it in C#, then you need to make the entire DataTemplate in C# and not in Xaml. May I ask why you want to make this in C# ?

Comment: I want to calculate the Height using the screen pixels. For that I need to do it in C#